# Jcarousel not rendering slides

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, jcarousel

Hi everyone i am very new to jquery, please help me in running the app on my system independent of jsfiddle  [this link](http://jsfiddle.net/blackdynamo/yxhzU/).. I have added below resource files in my app, but still it is not rendering the colour blocks..

this is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0rc2/jquery.mobile-1.0rc2.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0rc2/jquery.mobile-1.0rc2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="jquery.mobile.carousel.js" type="text/javascript" language="javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery.ui.ipad.js" type="text/javascript" language="javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

    $(document).ready(function($) {
        $("#carousel1").carousel();
    })(jQuery);

</script>
</head>
<body>
<div style="height: 300px; width: 500px">
    <ul id="carousel1" style="display: none;">
        <li><div style="width: 100%; height: 100%; background-color:#381;">Page 1</div></li>
        <li><div style="width: 100%; height: 100%; background-color:#837;">Page 2</div></li>
        <li><div style="width: 100%; height: 100%; background-color:#999;">Page 3</div></li>
        <li><div style="width: 100%; height: 100%; background-color:#738;">Page 4</div></li>
        <li><div style="width: 100%; height: 100%; background-color:#142;">Page 5</div></li>
        <li><div style="width: 100%; height: 100%; background-color:#927;">Page 6</div></li>
        <li><div style="width: 100%; height: 100%; background-color:#987;">Page 7</div></li>
        <li><div style="width: 100%; height: 100%; background-color:#187;">Page 8</div></li>
    </ul>
</div>
Vertical
<div style="height: 300px; width: 500px">
    <ul id="carousel2" style="display: none;">
        <li><div style="width: 100%; height: 100%; background-color:#381;">Page 1</div></li>
        <li><div style="width: 100%; height: 100%; background-color:#837;">Page 2</div></li>
        <li><div style="width: 100%; height: 100%; background-color:#999;">Page 3</div></li>
        <li><div style="width: 100%; height: 100%; background-color:#738;">Page 4</div></li>
        <li><div style="width: 100%; height: 100%; background-color:#142;">Page 5</div></li>
        <li><div style="width: 100%; height: 100%; background-color:#927;">Page 6</div></li>
        <li><div style="width: 100%; height: 100%; background-color:#987;">Page 7</div></li>
        <li><div style="width: 100%; height: 100%; background-color:#187;">Page 8</div></li>
    </ul>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

please help ... Thanks in advance...

Comment: I recommend running this in Google Chrome using the Developer Tools and taking a look at the error messages displayed in the Console.

Comment: Can you post the actual code from head tag, instead of 1,2,3?

Comment: You need to remove the `(jQuery)` from the end of line 8. The `$(document).ready()` doesn't return a function, but the `(jQuery)` tries to invoke one.

Comment: To Amar... if i post actual head tag then it considers as html file... so i have added numbers...

Comment: @user1065490: Paste the HTML, then highlight it and click the **`{ }`** button above the edit area. This will indent the code, which activates code formatting. (Or you can just indent it 4 spaces manually.)

Answer (score 0):

So, it looks like in line 8 you are trying to set #carousel1 as a carousel() once the DOM has loaded. Your lambda function looks slightly wrong to me. Your function($) should be function().

Comment: `function($)` is correct. The callback passes the global `jQuery` to that parameter.

Comment: Can u just visit http://jsfiddle.net/blackdynamo/yxhzU/ . I am trying to implement it independent of jsfiddle...

Comment: It's really only going to be of help to everyone if you either show us your code, or show us the javascript errors you are getting.